# Flutter application not launching when clicked on notification. C# Push notification Payload for mobile app developed using flutter

Tags: c#, android, flutter, firebase, push-notification

I am sending Push Notifications using **C#** to mobile application.
The application is created in **Flutter**.
My **C#** payload is :

```
notification = new
{
  icon = "Icon link here",
  badge = "Badge link here",
  title = "New Notification",
  body = "Message here",
  click_action = "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
  renotify = true,
},
```

The problem is after clicking on notification the application is not launched. While, when I send notifications through Firebase Console then after clicking on those notifications the application is launched.
In flutter projects android manifest file, I have added this :

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

So what can be the problem?
If problem is in payload then what is the proper payload to be used for sending notifications? Please suggest.
Thanks in advance!.